# MySQL empty result set on DATE(field) =

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

This query has no results and no errors.  Bar is datatype DATETIME.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE DATE(bar) = '2013-02-26';
```

This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),DATE(bar) FROM foo GROUP BY DATE(bar) ORDER BY DATE(bar) DESC;
```

Yields these results:

[image: results]

What am I doing wrong?

// EDIT
For some reason this works as expected...

```
 SELECT * FROM foo WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bar,'%Y-%m-%d') = "2013-02-26"
```

Comment: Not sure, works for me -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f0e4/1

Comment: @sgeddes: A `date` field is different from a `datetime` field, but it works either way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48f86/1

Comment: @RocketHazmat -- yes, I know that -- Just wrote it too quickly :D  But either way, OPs query should work.

Comment: Thanks folks.  I thought I was losing my mind.  If I find a solution or explanation I will post it.

Comment: Just found that this works as intended:  `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bar,'%Y-%m-%d') = "2013-02-26"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing "wrong" in the query you posted. There's no simple explanation as to why that query would return 0 rows.

To help debug the issue, I suggest you see if this query returns rows:

```
SELECT bar
  FROM foo
 WHERE DATE(bar) = '2013-02-26'
 LIMIT 10
```

or this

```
SELECT bar
  FROM foo
 WHERE bar >= '2013-02-26'
   AND bar  < '2013-02-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 LIMIT 10
```

(NOTE: The latter query can make use of an index range scan operation using an index with a leading column of `bar`; for the other query forms (which wrap the `bar` column in a `DATE` function, MySQL cannot use an index range scan.)

### Followup:

Next, check what value DATE(bar) is returning, by adding that expression to the SELECT list...

```
SELECT DATE(bar)
     , bar
  FROM foo
 WHERE bar >= '2013-02-26'
   AND bar  < '2013-02-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: The first query returns zero results.  The second query produces 10 rows of "2013-02-26 17:56:22" which is the correct value in the bar field in those rows.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: try adding `DATE(bar)` expression to the SELECT list, and see what it's returning.

Comment: I get 2013-02-26 17:56:22 and 2013-02-26 respectively for all rows.  Did you see my edit above about using DATE_FORMAT successfully?